# how to make supervisord immediately relive once it was killed

Tags: linux, supervisord

I finished installation of supervisord on my centos6, it works also well. But I found I could use command "kill" to kill supervisord itself, and it was not able to relive. I suppose when supervisord was killed it should relive immediately, otherwise it can not guarantee the subprocesses safe.

How should I make supervisord relive immediately once it was killed?

Comment: Run supervisor through another process management thing... until that one dies too.